# Select the right Azure technologies to store and to process weather forecasts data

Tags: azure, architecture, grib

I would like to download FTP files from NCEP GFS (Weather Forecasts data provider) and extract some parameters from them. After filtering (I need only temperatures and precipitations), I have roughly 1 GB of data in the GRIB format (binary) per day. Because these files contain "gridded data", SQL Azure is not (IMHO) the best solution to store such files (10 years of data leads to store 3 TB).
At the end, these files should be consumed by Azure ML and Power BI. The reporting involves some "geospatial joins" to aggregate gridded data by country, states and so on.

Do you have any idea about how to pick up the right technologies ?
I am a bit lost when I read the Azure documentation because there are too many data stores and it's difficult to understand the pros and cons of each of them : Azure Data Lake, HDInsight, etc.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards

Comment: FTP Site is ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/

Comment: Filtering of data is done using GriApi.NET : https://github.com/0x1mason/GribApi.NET

Comment: Hi @RudyCo, i'm really interested in this question. By now, which solutions did you adopt ?

Comment: Hi, I finally used Azure Storage V2

Answer (score 0):

In terms of data storage, you can store data in azure blob storage. May be a function app to process those files. This based on my little understanding of grided data.